# the art of "turning" phrases

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the underlined sentence mean "the act of using phrases in language is similar to the act of following a path in walking"?

[image: Scan of described text]

(Sound and Image in Western Art By Yael Kaduri)

Comment: I think the whole thing is trying to make a distinction between 'following' a path and 'making' your own path from the kits of parts of paths available to you. In the same way that you put together a phrase from the set of words available to you.

Comment: Look up "composing".  You do not understand what it means.

Comment: I know I say this on every one of your questions, but, again, his is just artcrit wordplay. It's not straightforward because the author *does not want it to be straightforward*. He wants to *force you into an act of interpretation*, and so forced you are: you'll have to come up with your own ideas for the parallels between walking a path and turning a phrase. Stop trying to find plain meaning in such passages. No one put any in for you to get out.

Comment: Also, 'turning a phrase',  isn't the same as 'using a phrase'. It denotes that you have crafted the phrase, creating something that did not exist before, and possibly has origins as a metaphor relating to turning wood on a lathe. The writer is talking about people constructing walks from elements of routes and phrases from words. Both are about creation, rather than use alone.

Answer (score 1):

The text is obviously translated from French. In French, *tourner* has for first meaning *to shape with a potter's wheel*, and has a figurative meaning that is not preserved in English translations:

> 2. Au fig. [Le compl. désigne des mots, un propos, un écrit] Arranger, présenter avec un certain style, disposer d'une manière adéquate au but recherché. *Savoir tourner un compliment, les mots d'un billet, un vers; tourner une lettre dans le beau style.*

(Trésor de la Langue Française)

That is, you can shape with style a beautiful sentence.

The word *tourner* is also employed for the way a stroller walks about, and the way and detours (one of the few words derived from French *tour* that keeps its exact meaning in English) they have taken can also, according to the author, express a personal style.